# Permutation with repetition of a list with variable list lentgh in Netlogo

Tags: permutation, netlogo

i´m new to Netlogo as well as programming and struggling on the following problem: I need to implement a function `Permu [k,n]` in Netlogo where k is a list of elements e.g `[1 2]` while n is the length of the resulting list e.g. `3`. The function should return all permutation say lists with length n where the elements are taken from k.

Example 1: `Permu [1 2] 3` should return as a result all permutations with repetition `[[1 1 1] [1 1 2] [1 2 1] [1 2 2] [2 1 1] [2 1 2] [2 2 1] [2 2 2]]`

Example 2: `Permu [1 2 3] 2` should return `[[1 1] [1 2] [1 3] [2 1] [2 2] [2 3] [3 1] [3 2] [3 3]]`

Actually, the equivalent function in Mathematica would be `Tuples[{1,2},3]`

I already checked post [Generating permutations of a list in NetLogo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815666/generating-permutations-of-a-list-in-netlogo), but was unable to adjust it to my needs.

Do you have any ideas how to do this or know some kind of pseudcode? Thanks in advance!

**Edit**

I came up with a (bad) solution by simply creating random lists made up of elements from k until all possible combinations are found:

```
to-report permu [k n]

  let number-of-all-combinations ( length k ) ^ n ;; stopping condtion

  let results []
  let temp-results []

  while [ length results < number-of-all-combinations ] [

    set temp-results []
    repeat n [ set temp-results fput (one-of k) temp-results ]
    if not member? temp-results results [set results fput temp-results results ] ;; makes sure that there are no duplicates in the result.
  ]

  report results

end
```

I would still appreciate a better alternative.Thanks!

Comment: What exactly means " unable to adjust". What errors showed up or what permutations were missing in your result set. A basic approach which we can improve together with you is really appreciated!

Comment: The function described there generated permutations of a given list without repetition e.g. Permu [ 1 2 ] returned [ [ 1 2 ] [ 2 1 ] ] while [1 1] and [2 2] where missing. But you are right about providing a basic approach, please check the edit. Sorry, first time for me!

Comment: No problem, now it's great for us all to start thinking! Don't worry, we all started some day here with our first question! :-)